# why Gson change property after release?

Tags: java, android, debugging, release, gson

My class is :

```
private static class CameraSize {
    public CameraSize(int h, int w) {
        this.h = h;
        this.w = w;
    }

    public int h;
    public int w;
}


List<CameraSize> lstCS=new LinkedList<>();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
for (int l = 0; l < listSize.size(); l++) {
    int height = listSize.get(l).height;
    int width = listSize.get(l).width;
    CameraSize cs = new CameraSize(height, width);
    lstCS.add(cs);
}
gson.toJson(lstCS);
```

Output in debug :

```
[{"h":1944,"w":2592},{"h":1458,"w":2592}]
```

Output in release :

```
[{"a":1944,"b":2592},{"a":1458,"b":2592}]
```

Why ??

Comment: Are you using proguard?

Comment: Yes. I used proguard and minifyEnablaed .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In release mode, as you said in comments, you have `minifyEnabled`.

Names of your fields are changed after the obfuscation process. If you want to hold them without obfuscation, you have to tell `Proguard` to keep them.

You can keep all nested `CameraSize` classes:

```
-keep class **$CameraSize { *; }
```

Or only the specific one:

```
-keep class your.package.to.outer.class.OuterName$CameraSize { *; }
```

You can optimize it more specifying fields:

```
-keepclassmembers class your.package.to.outer.class.OuterName$CameraSize {
    public int h;    
    public int w;
}
```

As user **@Marcin Koziński** said, you can also use `@Keep` annotation to your class/fields to avoid the obfuscation process.

In this case:

```
private static class CameraSize {
    public CameraSize(int h, int w) {
        this.h = h;
        this.w = w;
    }

    @Keep
    public int h;
    @Keep
    public int w;
}
```

Comment: In Android you can also just add `@Keep` annotation to the `CameraSize` class.

Comment: @MarcinKoziński It's right! By the way I still prefer to have my "keeps" all in proguard files to avoid to forget something.

Comment: I guess it's a personal preference. I always forget to add to the ProGuard file and it's easier for me to add `@Keep`s.